# PreventAppSheet not working as expected when configuring Email

Tags: ios, email

As per the apple documentation while configuring Email if PreventAppSheet is true then we cannot using the defined email with any 3rd party application like Gmail. But i am still able to send email even after PreventAppSheet is set to true.

What does PreventAppSheet actually mean.